# SQL Server: more than two tables for coalesce function

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I need help, I managed to get successful query for two tables, but I got error when I am trying to do more than two table. please help me.

This is the SQL:

```
select 
    coalesce(a.LOT_ID, b.LOT_ID,c.LOT_ID,d.LOT_ID) as LotId, 
    coalesce(a.CheckIn, b.CheckIn,c.CheckIn, d.CheckIn) as CheckIn,
    coalesce(a.CheckOut, b.CheckOut,c.CheckOut, d.CheckOut) as CheckOut,
    coalesce(a.StatusDesc, b.StatusDesc,c.StatusDesc, .StatusDesc) as StatusDesc
from 
    LOT_LOC_BOND a, LOT_LOC_IEBT b,LOT_LOC_MBT c,LOT_LOC_SEAL d
where   
    a.LOT_ID = b.LOT_ID,
    AND c.LOT_ID = d.LOT_ID
```

and the error stated

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing alias name at the end

```
coalesce(a.StatusDesc, b.StatusDesc,c.StatusDesc, .StatusDesc) --d is missing
```

start using `INNER JOIN` syntax to join tables

```
SELECT COALESCE(nullif(a.LOT_ID,''), nullif(b.LOT_ID,''), nullif(c.LOT_ID,''), nullif(d.LOT_ID,'')) AS LotId,
       COALESCE(a.CheckIn, b.CheckIn, c.CheckIn, d.CheckIn) AS CheckIn,
       COALESCE(a.CheckOut, b.CheckOut, c.CheckOut, d.CheckOut) AS CheckOut,
       COALESCE(a.StatusDesc, b.StatusDesc, c.StatusDesc, d.StatusDesc) AS StatusDesc --missing alias name d  
FROM   LOT_LOC_BOND a
       INNER JOIN LOT_LOC_IEBT b
               ON a.LOT_ID = b.LOT_ID
       INNER JOIN LOT_LOC_MBT c
               ON a.LOT_ID = c.LOT_ID
       INNER JOIN LOT_LOC_SEAL d
               ON c.LOT_ID = d.LOT_ID
```

Comment: wow that is very helpfull,I'm so careless.thank you anyway . I have tried your correction but I don't understand why my LOT_ID is empty?

Comment: @Joojoo - Coalesce will not return the first non empty value. It will return the first not null value, probably any of the `LOT_ID` has empty in it so it is returned